# Generalization of fisher inequality

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

What upper bounds are known on the size of a family $\mathcal{S}$ of subsets $S_i \subset [N]$ such that:

i) each $S_i$ is of size $pk$.

ii) for $i \neq j$, $|S_i \cap S_j| \bmod p \in U$, for some set $U$ of residues modulo $p$ with $|U| = L$?

From Fisher's inequality style arguments (see [here](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~anuprao/pubs/CSE599sExtremal/lecture13.pdf)), it is not too hard to show that

$$|\mathcal{S}| \leq \sum_{i=0}^{Lk}\binom{N}{i}$$

However, if $0 \not\in U$, then by working modulo $p$, you can get the much stronger inequality

$$|\mathcal{S}| \leq \sum_{i=0}^{L}\binom{N}{i}$$

Is it possible to get a better bound than the first inequality in the case where $0 \in U$? The best lower bound I am aware of comes from constructing the $S_i$ as unions of $p$-tuples, where you get a lower bound of something like $\binom{N/p}{k}$.